# Hibernation turns off screen, but doesn't seem to actually hibernate. Cannot resume, only force shutdown

Tags: boot, lubuntu, suspend, swap, hibernate

I have never been able to hibernate my laptop with lubuntu but now that I have 20.04 I want to get it to work desperately. I am very much a noob when it comes to computers. I have tried pretty much all options to try and fix hibernation for lubuntu and ubuntu in the past. None work. The screen simply dims, but the fan and disk keep spinning and the light at the front is still on, indicating that it hasn't gone into hibernation at all. I can however also not resume from this state and have to hold the power key down to boot again.

- Lubuntu 20.04
- No dual boot. Lubuntu is the only OS
- 4gb of RAM, 7gb swap partition
- My Grub points to my swap UUID for resume
- /etc/polkit-1/localauthority includes "disk"
- normal suspend (not to disk) seems to work fine
- fast/secure boot disabled

I have searched every possible forum on this issue and no solution seems to work. I tried everything multiple times over the last two years, with multiple Lubuntu versions. This question really is desperation. I cannot figure out why it doesn't work. Thank you.

EDIT:
I was asked to post some more info.

The device is an ASUS F553M laptop which originally came with windows. All of the hardware is still the original.
It doesn't really have a graphics card, just an integrated chip. `sudo lspci | grep VGA` gives me:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
```

I don't have a swap file, I have a swap partition I created when installing from USB to an empty disk.
[These are my partitions in KDE partition manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf1AQ.png)

This is what my grub looks like (without comments):

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=1
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="resume=UUID=466f0c76-dcd1-40f4-964a-45a8fdc34dec"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

EDIT2: some more info relating to swap

`cat /etc/fstab` output:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=763C-4C14                            /boot/efi      vfat    umask=0077 0 2
UUID=11574a78-b833-49f8-b193-457c8109fe4d /              ext4    defaults   0 1
UUID=5f07ad92-5724-405f-8705-e95f607c79ac /home          ext4    defaults   0 2
UUID=466f0c76-dcd1-40f4-964a-45a8fdc34dec swap           swap    defaults   0 2
```

`free` output:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        3914788      840572     2364952       74924      709264     2771316
Swap:       7168524           0     7168524
```

`sudo swapon -s` output:

```
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda4                               partition       7168524 0       -2
```

Comment: Add the type of computer and the graphics card to your question if it has one.  That will help us help you.

Comment: Is your path to `resume=UUID=XXXXXXXX.XXXX...` located on the linux line of your grub.cfg. When I install 20.04, the installer creates a swapfile, not partition. A swapfile also requires `resume_offset=XXXXX` in grub.cfg.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247133/how-to-handle-full-install-usb-and-swap-space, concerns bootable USB devices, but may be applicable here.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. I have updated the post with some more info.

Comment: Is swap partition UUID is listed in `/etc/fstab`? If you go to Disks is swapon? Does `free` show the swap? how about `sudo swapon -s`?

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure what you mean by "go to Disks" in the second question. As far as I can tell my swap is active. I added some more info.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your question you are not a NOOB. Your information is precise and very good.
Try the following in a **root** terminal :

```
echo platform > /sys/power/disk
echo disk > /sys/power/state
```

If platform works, add it to  `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf`:

```
[Sleep]
HibernateMode=platform
```

else try it with "shutdown" (this helped me alot of times)