# What is the default swap file size for Desktop and Server environments? is fixed?

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, swap

According with the following link:

- [Is wise and safe use "swap file" for PC/Laptops of 8GB or less? either HDD or SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399723/is-wise-and-safe-use-swap-file-for-pc-laptops-of-8gb-or-less-either-hdd-or-ss)

Since Ubuntu 17:04 is used by default `swap file`.

The main questions is:

- What is the default size defined for the Desktop and Server environments?

Secondary questions:

- Are they equals?
- Being equals or not - is it fixed? or is defined at real time according with the current hardware where Ubuntu is being installed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [swap partition vs swap file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904372/swap-partition-vs-swap-file). Also https://askubuntu.com/q/178712 and https://askubuntu.com/q/927854 and others. You can search Ask Ubuntu for answers to these questions and more. After your research, if you are still unsure or if you have a new question that hasn't been asked, you can start a new question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I have root partition on my SSD and swap partition on HDD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287915/can-i-have-root-partition-on-my-ssd-and-swap-partition-on-hdd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default swap size. There's no "one size fits all" value.

The size of swap (contiguous) file or swap partition is governed by what you want to happen when your programs run out of RAM.

If you have no swap, the dreaded OOM-Killer runs, and picks a process to kill to free memory.

If you have some swap, programs can be "swapped out" to free memory, and your system continues, albeit slightly slower (additional disk I/O). When your programs run out of memory plus swap, it's the OOM-Killer again.

If you have at least as much swap as RAM, you can hibernate your system.

If you have all the swap in the world, your programs can seem to use all the memory in the world, but your system will run very slowly, constantly swapping.

Comment: Just for your consideration - https://askubuntu.com/a/1389173/970554