# Ubuntu works on USB, does that necessarily mean it supports my machine?

Tags: system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu 23.04 on an old laptop, I tried it on the laptop with the USB drive and it worked. Does that necessarily mean that it will also work when installed on the computer?

Comment: Probably - but make sure you check all the features that you’ll need are working - eg wifi, touchpad, Bluetooth etc.

Comment: Yes - you might have problems with hibernation (which you can't check with USB), but the live version uses your hardware - so you are ready to go.

Comment: With a computer less than fifteen years old, you can think of a USB as just another hard drive.

Comment: @kanehekili: Hibernation will work on a full install USB, See: https://askubuntu.com/a/1247151/43926

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, basically it should work. That's the purpose of booting a live session from USB - to check if Ubuntu works with your computer. If live session works, then most probably installed system will work as well.